# Позиционирование элементов в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Есть 7 картинок. Мне нужно чтобы 5 картинок были в ряд на одной строке а 2 снизу на другой в центре и тоже в ряд. 5 картинок в ряд у меня получилось сделать, но почему-то не получается сделать 2 снизу в центре и не получается сделать их всех круглыми на 100% в `responsive` версии. Что не так? 
Вот html:

```
 <div class="picture-box">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ring">
                        <img src="img/team/1.jpg">
                            <h5>LOrem impsum</h5> 
                            <p>LOrem impsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Вот css:

```
.picture-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

  }
  .ring {
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
  }

.ring img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.picture-box h5, p {
    color: #414141;
    text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .ring {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .ring img {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .picture-box h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .picture-box p {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .picture-box h5, p {
        margin-bottom: -5px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .ring img {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }    
}
```

Использую `Bootsrtap4`. Если можно без него, то подскажите как, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант без бутстрапа.

```
<div class="picture-box">

     <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>
   <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="ring">
            <img src="img/5.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.picture-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

  }
  .ring {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
    margin: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: спасибо! Отметил как правильный!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: а можно еще вопрос, я под каждой картинкой 2 строки текста написал, но они не по центру от картинки, т.е снизу и по центру нужно и в мобильной версии тексты наезжают друг на друга, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите, как это выглядит или дайте посмотреть актуальный на сей момент код. На вскидку, могу предложить использовать связку figure / fig-caption.

Comment: я обновил вопрос с ваши кодом, и своими добавлениями, посмотрите пожалуйста. Мне нужно чтобы на IPad они тоже были 5 в ряд и снизу 2, а там 6 в ряд и одна снизу + текст(описание) не по центру, сделал через css, но что-то не совсем работает, посмотрите где ошибка. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно всё понял, то вот это поможет.

```
 .ring {
    width: 180px;
    margin: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;

 }

.ring img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto; 

}
```